# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locals' of undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, webpack, bundle, asp.net-core-3.1

I've made bundle.js and bundle.css to use in my web app,

My package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        //Define entry point
        entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/css/index.scss'],

        //Define output point
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery'
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'bundle.css'
            })
        ]

    };
};
```

My src structure is like this:

[src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmL0f.png)

index.js:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import './js/login';
import './js/helpers';
```

index.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'util.scss';
@import 'login.scss';
@import 'site.css';
```

I am getting this error in console:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT7Ib.png)

[bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suARy.png)

Everything else is working fine, i have no problem with javascript, but it bugs me that i don't know how to fix this error.

PS:
I am new to web development in general, started using webpack yesterday, the idea was to use only bundle.js and bundle.css in my html without adding jquery and bootstrap tags for them separately

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to set the option esModule to false for MiniCssExtractPlugin

```
use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: {
            esModule: false,
        },
    },
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader'
]
```

Comment: Can somebody explain what was the cause of the error and why `esModule: false` helped?

Comment: could you explain why need tweak like this?@Dina

Answer (score 3):

Don't use 'style-loader' along with mini-css-extract-plugin, modify your rule to match the below:

```
{
    test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    use: [
            //'style-loader',
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
         ]
},
```

You can find more details here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/613

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Dina's answer but without `MiniCssExtractPlugin` :

```
use: [
    {
      loader: "style-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false,
      },
    },
    "css-loader",
    "sass-loader",
  ]
```